# Submitting forms containing multiple selects in Play Framework for Scala

Tags: forms, scala, html-select, playframework-2.3

I have a multiple select item in a Form. According to Play Framework's documentation, I need 'repeated values' to make all the selected options fit into a List[String] property of my data structure.

```
case class MyFormData (
  fq_cset:  Option[List[String]]
)


val myForm: Form[MyFormData] = Form(
  mapping(
     "fq_cset" -> optional(list(text))
  )
)(MyFormData.apply _)(MyFormData.unapply _)
```

I quote Play's documentation:

*When you are using repeated data like this, the form values sent by the browser must be named emails[0], emails[1], emails[2], etc.*

I cannot figure out how to name the values like mentioned above. I tried to create a select element like this one

```
<select name="fq_cset">
  <option name="fq_cset[0]" value="A" selected="selected">Value A</option>
  <option name="fq_cset[1]" value="B"                    >Value B</option>
  <option name="fq_cset[2]" value="C" selected="selected">Value C</option>
  <option name="fq_cset[3]" value="D"                    >Value D</option>
</select>
```

but after submitting the form I see in the URL

```
/path?fq_cset=A&fq_cset=C
```

instead of

```
/path?fq_cset[0]=A&fq_cset[2]=C
```

The absence of the indexes enclosed in square brackets, prevents the correct binding of the parameters in the List[String] property named fq_cset in MyFormData class.

How can I get this to work properly? Is this the right approach to get what I need or I misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: That documentation doesn't really apply to multiple select elements. You want to set the name of the `select` to `fq_cset[]`. Don't set name on `option`, that doesn't do anything. Also, you forgot `multiple` on your select. See [this](https://gist.github.com/Timshel/6019293) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, it works splendidly